# Delete all drawn shapes JAVA

Tags: java, graphics2d, shapes

I need to delete shapes individually or all of them!
please help I've tried deleting all contents from my `arrayList` "Figuras"
and `removeAll` from panel

```
public class PaintRodo extends JFrame {

    JButton linea, circulo, rectangulo, trazo, llenar,borrar;
    static  int seleccion = 1;
    Color trazoC  = Color.BLACK;
    Color llenarC = Color.lightGray;
    JMenuBar barra;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new PaintRodo();
    }

public PaintRodo() {
    this.setSize(1000,700);
    this.setTitle("Paint");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    Box miBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    linea= AgregarIcono("./src/linea.png",2);
    circulo= AgregarIcono("./src/circ.png",3);
    rectangulo= AgregarIcono("./src/rect.png",4);
    trazo = AgregarIconoColor("./src/trazo.png",5,true);
    llenar = AgregarIconoColor("./src/llenar.png",6,false);
    borrar =  AgregarIcono("./src/borrador.png",7);
    miBox.add(linea);
    miBox.add(circulo);
    miBox.add(rectangulo);
    miBox.add(llenar);
    miBox.add(trazo);
    miBox.add(borrar);
    panel.add(miBox);
    this.add(panel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(new Lienzo(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.setVisible(true);
}   

public JButton AgregarIcono (String icono, final int accion){
    JButton boton = new JButton();
    Icon iconos = new ImageIcon (icono);
    boton.setIcon(iconos);

    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        seleccion =accion;  

    }

    });
    return boton;

}

public JButton AgregarIconoColor (String icono, final int accion,final boolean grosor ){
    JButton boton = new JButton();
    Icon iconos = new ImageIcon (icono);
    boton.setIcon(iconos);

    boton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(grosor){
            trazoC = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"Elige el Contorno",Color.BLACK);
        }
        else{
            llenarC = JColorChooser.showDialog(null,"Elige el Relleno",Color.BLACK);
        }

    }

    });
    return boton;

}

public class Lienzo extends JComponent{
    ArrayList<Shape> figuras = new ArrayList<Shape>();
    ArrayList<Color> arrLleno = new ArrayList<Color>();
    ArrayList<Color> arrTrazo = new ArrayList<Color>();
    Point inicio,fin;


    public Lienzo(){




        this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
                if (seleccion!=1){
                inicio = new Point (e.getX(),e.getY());
                fin=inicio;
                repaint();
                }

            }
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
                if (seleccion!=1){
                Shape SAVEfig=null;
                if (seleccion==2){
                     SAVEfig = crearLinea(inicio.x,inicio.y,e.getX(),e.getY());
                }
                else if (seleccion==3){
                     SAVEfig = crearCirculo(inicio.x,inicio.y,e.getX(),e.getY());

                }




                figuras.add(SAVEfig);
                arrLleno.add(llenarC);
                arrTrazo.add(trazoC);   
                repaint();
            }   

            }
        });//mouselistener

        this.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter(){
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){

                fin= new Point (e.getX(),e.getY());
                repaint();

            }

        });//MotionListener


    }//constructor lienzo

    public void paint (Graphics g){

        Graphics2D graFig = (Graphics2D)g;
        graFig.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        graFig.setStroke (new BasicStroke(2));
        Iterator<Color>contadorTrazo= arrTrazo.iterator();
        Iterator<Color>contadorLleno= arrLleno.iterator();
        graFig.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,1.0f));
        this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        for (Shape i: figuras){
            graFig.setPaint(contadorTrazo.next());
            graFig.draw(i);
            graFig.setPaint(contadorLleno.next());
            graFig.fill(i);
        }

        if (inicio!=null&&fin!=null){
            graFig.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER,0.40f));
            graFig.setPaint(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
            Shape SAVEfig=null;

            if (seleccion==2){
                SAVEfig=crearLinea(inicio.x,inicio.y,fin.x,fin.y);
            }
            else if (seleccion==3){
                SAVEfig=crearCirculo(inicio.x,inicio.y,fin.x,fin.y);
            }


            graFig.draw(SAVEfig);

        }



    }

    private Rectangle2D.Float crearRectangulo(int x1, int y1,int x2 , int y2){
        int x =Math.min(x1, x2);
        int y =  Math.min(y1, y2);

        int ancho = Math.abs(x1-x2);
        int alto = Math.abs(y1-y2);
        return new Rectangle2D.Float(x,y,ancho,alto);
    }
     private Line2D.Float crearLinea(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
         return new Line2D.Float(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

      private Ellipse2D.Float crearCirculo( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
          int x = Math.min(x1, x2);
          int y = Math.min(y1, y2);
          int ancho = Math.abs(x1 - x2);
          int alto = Math.abs(y1 - y2);
          return new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, ancho, alto);
      }






}//classLienzo



 }//MainClass Paint rodo
```

I need to delete shapes individually or all of them!
Please help; I've tried deleting all contents from my arrayList "Figuras"
and (removeAll) from panel

Comment: Never use `src` in any path, the path will not exist once the project is exported

Comment: `Box` isn't a "layout" tool, it's suppose to be used in conjunction with `BoxLayout`

Comment: `i've tried deleting all contents from my arrayList "Figuras" ` - where? I don't see any code that does that. It works fine for me. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). That example deletes the objects from an ArrayList to clear the panel.

Comment: i'll try that @camickr thanks! btw I deleted that part of the code because it wouldn't let me compile it